"Module 'audioplayers_darwin' not found in Flutter project on macOS Sequoia 15 with Xcode 16.1"
I am working on a Flutter project on macOS Sequoia 15 with Xcode 16.1, running on VMware. When trying to build the project, I encounter the following error:
Module 'audioplayers_darwin' not found

Steps Taken:

Ran flutter clean to clear the build artifacts.
Executed flutter pub get to fetch dependencies.
Ran flutter pub upgrade to ensure dependencies are up to date.
Navigated to the ios folder and ran pod install without any issues.

Key Details:

GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h contains the following import logic:
#if __has_include(<audioplayers_darwin/AudioplayersDarwinPlugin.h>)
#import <audioplayers_darwin/AudioplayersDarwinPlugin.h>
#else
@import audioplayers_darwin;
#endif


The Podfile specifies:
platform :ios, '12.0'
use_frameworks!
flutter_ios_podfile_setup

(Full Podfile content is included below.)

The pubspec.yaml includes:
audioplayers: ^6.1.0
vibration: ^2.0.1
device_info_plus: ^11.2.0
path_provider: ^2.5.3



Environment:

macOS: Sequoia 15 (VMware)
Flutter: 3.5.3
Xcode: 16.1
iOS Deployment Target: 12.0 (as specified in Podfile)


Question:
What could be causing the Module 'audioplayers_darwin' not found error, and how can I resolve it? Are there any additional steps or configurations I should check for this setup?
Do I need to explicitly add any Podfile configurations for audioplayers_darwin, or could there be an issue with how the plugin is being linked?
Any insights or troubleshooting steps would be appreciated.
